# Please, recommend audio player embbed in IE browser

Tags: audio, mp3, wowza

We have stored audio sources in WOWZA server.
We are researching a audio player to playback these in Web Browser over RTMP or HTTP(HLS).
Essential features are to seek specific point and to change play rate(x2, x4...).
We have tested HTML5 audio tag, but it does not support RTMP and HLS streaming.
How about JWplayer and flowplayer? They support these two features?
Please let me know appropriate audio player.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JwPLayer for audio/html5 with HLS protocol. HLS works on iOS and Android > 4.1 (only if you use aac codec, mp3 works only using progressive download)

more infos: http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/

**Update**
Example, with primary flash option enabled. (remember HLS with Mp3 files doesn't work on Android)

```
jwplayer('').setup({playlist: [{
    image: 'example.png',
    file:'http://www.example.com:1935/store-1/_definst_/MP3:AUDIO.mp3/playlist.m3u8',
    primary: 'flash',
 });
```

**Note** 
To be able to use this option (HLS with flash player) you must have JW Player Premium or Enterprise Edition.

Comment: thank you for you answer. But audio/html5 not worked in desktop browser(I.E) over HLS. And flowplayer&jwplayer with flash not support to increase audio playback speed. So confusing.

Comment: For me it works correctly with  with jwPlayer using primary flash option. Now I update my answer with an example

Comment: To increase audio playback speed you can use javascript api "playbackRate" (only for html5), example here:  http://www.jwplayer.com/labs/experiments/playback-rate/